# backend to front message translator

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following structure to perform the translate in the backend for messages sent to the front.

for each language i have a **messages.properties**

- messages.properties **(default EN)**
- messages_es.properties
- messages_pt_BR.properties

On each endpoint, I receive as a parameter a Locale, coming from the front-end, and to get a message to be returned to the front-end, I delegate to the messageSource injected into my service as follows.

**Ex:**

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource translate;

public String message(String value, Locale locale) {
        
   return translate.getMessage(value, new Object[]{"Hello.."}, locale);
}
```

It works perfectly!

But my application requires something more efficient after I run into some problems.
One of the problems, some values ​​returned from the base need to be translated, eg enun descriptions.

Today I do the following.

**Example of an enum**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum PersonType {
    PHYSICAL("F","messages.enum.personType.physicalPerson.description"),
    LEGAL("L","messages.enum.personType.legalPerson.description");
    
    private String code;
    private String description; // key inside messages.properties file   
}
```

**Service**

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource translate;

@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository;

public PersonInfoDTO findById(Long id, Locale locale) {

    return personRepository.findById(id)
            .map(translateEnums(locale))
            .orElseThrow(NoResultException::new);
}

private Function<PersonInfoDTO, PersonInfoDTO> translateEnums(Locale locale) {
    return obj -> {
        obj.setPersonType(translate.getMessage(obj.getPersonType().getDescription(), null, locale));
        return obj;
    };
}
```

**DTO**

```
@Builder
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PersonInfoDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String fantasyName;
    @Setter
    private String personType;
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Builder
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Person")
public class PersonEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String fantasyName;
    private PersonType personType;
}
```

I would like to build something simpler, sometimes an enum, but I have the problem of the entity being a property
of type PersonType and the DTO value is a string.

If anyone has a suggestion, or if you had the same problem.